# Galaxy Tab A's Bluetooth draining battery when Bluetooth isn't on

Tags: bluetooth, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

My Samsung Galaxy Tab A just upgraded to Android 7.1. My battery life decreased dramatically after the update. What used to give me days of battery life now only lasts me hours. I checked my battery stats, and this is what I found:
[image: Image of usage percentages]
Bluetooth was using most of my battery, but Bluetooth isn't even enabled! What is causing this immense drain of battery from a feature that hasn't been enabled?

Comment: A friend I have that also recently got the update on a different Samsung device has been having issues with shortened battery life as well. I'm not sure if it is the Bluetooth on his though.

Comment: If it's an option for you, you could try performing a [factory-reset](/tags/factory-reset/info) of your device (WARNING: All data will be lost, so be sure to have relevant stuff backed up). It could be the update messed up some configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also turn off those 2 flags in GPS settings.
[image: GPS settings]

Comment: Yeah this fixed it for me. Since I forgot to post this answer on my own. You can have it. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 0):

Settings is broken.

Either it's not turning off Bluetooth or the battery history is flat wrong.

I've seen both types of errors over the years.

If the set won't turn off Bluetooth radio power, no amount of force stopping or add on apps is likely to save you.

Nonetheless, maybe they missed something so go at it from another angle.

Check out "Power Toggles"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc

If you're using an add-on task manager, stop, most of them flat out lie, and try GSam Battery Monitor.